# Spring boot org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Utilisateur is not mapped (with MYSQL)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Hi I am using Mysql with Spring boot and when i am using the query method with the CrudRepository hibernate can't match with my table.

My User class :

```
@Entity

@Table(name="Utilisateur")

public class User{

    @Id
    private long id;
    @Column(name="nom")
    private String nom;
    @Column(name="prenom")
    private String prenom;
    @Column(name="admin")
    private boolean admin;
    @Column(name="actif")
    private boolean actif;
    @Column(name="logins")
    private String logins;
    @Column(name="email")
    private String email;
    @Column(name="naissance")
    private String naissance;
    @Column(name="pwd")
    private String pwd;
    @Column(name="compte")
    private String compte;

    public User(){

    }

    public User(String nom, String prenom, boolean admin, boolean actif, String logins, String email, String naissance, String pwd, String compte) {
        this.nom = nom;
        this.prenom = prenom;
        this.admin = admin;
        this.actif = actif;
        this.logins = logins;
        this.email = email;
        this.naissance = naissance;
        this.pwd = pwd;
        this.compte = compte;
    }
/*Getters and setters*/
}
```

My second class implement CrudRepository :

```
@Repository
public interface UserDao  extends CrudRepository<User,Long>{

    public User findByEmail(String email);
    public List<User> findByLogins(String logins);
    public List<User> findAll();

    @Query("SELECT u FROM Utilisateur u where id=?1")
    public User findById(int Id);
}
```

And for finish i am using a class for test with junit :

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = RecipyApplication.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
public class RecipyApplicationTests {

    @Autowired
    private UserDao userDao;
    @Test
    public void should_get_user_by_id(){
        User user = userDao.findById(1);
        Assert.assertNotNull("the id can't be null ",user);
    }

}
```

And i don't understand why hibernate can't match with my database when i am using @Query. Thank you

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Instead of `SELECT u FROM Utilisateur` use `SELECT u FROM User` in the @Query.

We should use entity name rather than table name.

Comment: Thank you very much but why the query not match with the table Utilisateur if I specified in my User class the table name ? thank you

Comment: @zaafrani The reason being, while writing `jpql` or `query` it expects us to use entity name. Incase if you want to use `Utilisateur` you need to specify it in the entity annotation. Example `entity(name="Utilisateur")`.

Answer (score 3):

An alternative solution to this can be that you forgot to put **nativeQuery** attribute in the **@Query**.

```
@Query("SELECT u FROM Utilisateur u where id=?1")
public User findById(int Id);
```

should have been

```
@Query("SELECT u FROM Utilisateur u where id=?1", nativeQuery=true)
public User findById(int Id);
```